# Using CartoDB Infowindow on fullscreen of iPad?

Tags: carto, infowindow, ipad

We're just about ready to go with our first ever CartoDB visualisation, namely a map of the museums in Britain.

Unfortunately I'm having a rather large issue with infowindow positioning in either desktop fullscreen or when viewed on an iPad. In short, when clicked on fullscreen then the infowindows appear about 1,000 miles south of their marker. On an iPad it seems to be around 1,000 miles north of their marker. The code for the infowindow is as follows:

```
<div class="cartodb-popup">
<a href="#close" class="cartodb-popup-close-button close">x</a>
<div class="cartodb-popup-content-wrapper">
<divclass="cartodb-popup-content">
<p style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #078971">{{destination_name}}</p>
<h4>county</h4>
<p>{{county}}</p>
<h4>Type of Museum</h4>
<p>{{destination_type}}</p>
<h4>description</h4>
<p>{{description}}</p>
<p><a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">Visit the Museum's Website</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The URL for the visualisation is at http://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryMagazine/DestinationsUK/Museums/

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your infowindow code and seems like there is a problem with the HTML.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33489446/Screen%20Shot%202014-04-30%20at%204.38.19%20PM.png

Maybe the close div tag is not ok.